# Piperic acid oxidation

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image: Question 3b iii)]

There are 2 double bonds $\ce{C=C}$ present within each piperic acid molecule,  thus when piperic acid reacts with hot excess $\ce{KMnO4}$, it oxidised into a carboxyllic acid. Why is $\ce{CO2}$ produced?

The carbon atom bonded directly to the benzene ring will get oxidised into a carboxylic acid and also that the carbon bonded to the $\ce{COOH}$ group will get oxidized also to a carboxylic acid to form a dicarboxylic acid. What changes will take place to the other 2 carbon atoms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> this paper stated that $\ce{CO2}$   could be formed as well, how?

Usually when we consider permanganate oxidations we think of

- oxidation of alkyl benzenes to benzoic acid
- cleavage and oxidation of a double bond to an acid, through the aldehyde, if there is one hydrogen on the double bond
- cleavage and oxidation of a double bond to a ketone if there are no hydrogens on the double bond

However, there are a few **special cases** such as formic acid and oxalic acid, or their corresponding aldehydes.  These compounds are oxidized by permanganate to $\ce{CO2}$ (for an idea as to why these compounds react differently than, say, acetic acid, see Scheme 1 [here](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Laszlo_Kotai/publication/257955325_Kinetics_and_mechanism_of_oxidation_of_formic_and_oxalic_acids_by_bis(pyridine)silver_permanganate/links/0c96052c7cdb355b72000000.pdf)).

With this information in hand we can re-examine the permanganate oxidation of piperic acid.

[image]

We see that oxalic acid is one of the primary products produced in this reaction.  As discussed above, oxalic acid can then undergo further reaction to produce carbon dioxide.

Comment: It's my first time to hear about this. so i should learn that in those cases, CO2 is produced, yes?. Is this applied to some aldehydes?

Comment: Yes, you should be aware of the permanganate oxidation of those 2 molecules **and their aldehydes**.  Since this is your first time here, let me add that if this answer was helpful please consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and\or [up-voting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it, thanks.